# javascript convert string into array of int with brackets

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split, int

I have a string that contains an array with numbers in square bracket like this [1, 2,3, 4]. I want convert that string into array of integers. I can use split function but I also need to strip of square brackets and remove spaces if any between the numbers.

Comment: Try [*match*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-string.prototype.match), then the input doesn't need to be valid JSON.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

if you already have the string like this `"[1, 2,3, 4]"`  JSON.parse will do

```
var arr = JSON.parse( "[1, 2,3, 4]" );
```